# JS input field cursor focus if its a child element in a div

Tags: javascript, select, focus

Got more parent divs and each got multiple child elements while one of those childs is an input field of text type.

Parent divs are being randomly shown one by another and I need JS to target particular child input to focus blinking cursor for user into the child whenever a parent div is being shown.

I tried this but it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div>A</div>
 <div>B</div>
 <div>C</div>
 <input>D</input>
</div>
..
<div class="parent">
 <div>A</div>
 <div>B</div>
 <div>C</div>
 <input>D</input>
</div>
..
<div class="parent">
 <div>A</div>
 <div>B</div>
 <div>C</div>
 <input>D</input>
</div>
```

Particular JS line:

```
$('.parent:eq(' + random + ')').show().focus().select();
```

Entire JS function:

```
function show() {
  used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
  $('.parent').hide();
  for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
    var random = get_random_number();
    $('.parent:eq(' + random + ')').show().focus().select();
  }
  $('.parent').delay(9500).fadeOut(500);
}
```

I can't seem to find how to target input as a child element and make JS focus a cursor on it and then so on with every other parent class div being shown. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: do you only ever have 1 parent div being shown at a time?

Comment: yes I got 1 parent div being shown at a time, others are hidden, and then again, one random parent div will appear, and so on..

Answer (score 1):

So, based on Andrew's remarks, I found the solution. Didn't realize so I forgot that each child input has it's own ID...

FINAL WORKING JS:

```
function show() {
  used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
  $('.parent').hide();
  $('.parent > input').blur();
  for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
    var random = get_random_number();
    $('.parent:eq(' + random + ')').show();
    $('.parent > input').select();
  }
  $('.parent').delay(9500).fadeOut(500);
}
```

So In my case really helped using .select method and after each cycle of parent div shown, use even method .blur to defocus particular unique input.

Again, taking in mind all child inputs have their own IDs (which I forgot to list in the beginning, once again sorry for the misconception).

Answer (score 0):

Since you only ever have 1 parent showing at a time you can just focus on the child input of the parent div.

You can show the parent and then focus on the input. I think you were trying to do too much in 1 line of code with `$('.parent:eq(' + random + ')').show().focus().select();`

For example, you can use `show()` on the parent and `focus()` on the input that is now being shown.

```js
const div_number = 1;
const get_random_number = () => 0;

function show() {
  //used_numbers.splice(0, used_numbers.length);
  $('.parent').hide();

  for (var inc = 0; inc < div_number; inc++) {
    var random = get_random_number();
    $('.parent:eq(' + random + ')').show();
    $('.parent > input').focus();
  }
  $('.parent').delay(9500).fadeOut(500);
}

show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
 <div>A</div>
 <div>B</div>
 <div>C</div>
 <input>D</input>
</div>

<div class="parent">
 <div>A</div>
 <div>B</div>
 <div>C</div>
 <input>D</input>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now its working but only with first parent div being show. Others inputs are not focused. I got different ID on inputs, maybe that's the problem? Probably I need to focus each time the unique child input. Any idea on this?

Comment: Oh now I got solution myself based on ur answer, going to post it down below. Many thanks.